# Python Regex Negative Lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have a large database of CT scan results and impressions. I am attempting to build a regular expression which searches for an integer or floating number followed by 'mm' that is neighboring the word 'nodule' ahead or behind. This is the regular expression I have for this so far:

```
nodule_4mm_size = "(?s).*?([0-4]*\.*[0-9]+\s*[mM]{2})[\w\W]{0,24}[Nn]odule|(?s)[Nn]odule[\w\W]{0,24}.*?([0-4]*\.*[0-9]+\s*[mM]{2})”
```

However, I need to ensure that these findings are not preceded by previous or prior measurements. Radiologists referring to previous scans. So I am trying a negative lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<!previously measured)\?[Nn]odule[\w\W]{0,24}[^\.\d]([0-4]\s*[mM]{2}|[0-3]\.[0-9]\s*[mM]{2}|4\.0+\s*[mM]{2})
```

However, I can't get it to work. Take for instance the following paragraph.

> "For example, the largest nodule which is located in the right lower
>   lobe and currently measures 4.4 mm (image #82, series 3) previously
>   measured 3.6 mm on 09/01/2011."

In this case, I would like the regex to hit on 4.4 mm not 3.6 mm.  Furthermore, if multiple hits are found I would like to only keep the largest size found. For example,

> "For example, the largest nodule which is located in the right lower
>   lobe and currently measures 4.4 mm (image #82, series 3) previously
>   measured 3.6 mm on 09/01/2011. Another nodule was found measuring 2.2 mm.

In this case I would like to ensure only 4.4 mm is identified.

Any help would truly be appreciated. Just can't get this negative lookbehind to work! Thanks!

Comment: `[previously measured]` means match a character in the following set: `p`, `r`, `e`, `v`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `s`, `l`, `y`, " ", `m`, `a`, and `d`. `[^\.\d]` means match a character not in the following set: "\", `.`, `[0-9]`.

Comment: [Learn what a character class is.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: How is it supposed to know with multiple hits that a hit isn't just a reference to a previous scan?  Do the measurements always follow a certain series?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as per Sam's suggestion on character class the negative lookbehind statement should not be in brackets, my mistake. I have edited this. What I mean by taking the max is that, by getting this statement to work and finding all hits that do not qualify as coming after previously measured within a certain amount of white space, by one method, I can do  `p = re.findall(nodule_size,row['Result'])` and take the max per row from the output. However, there may be a better way, I am relatively new to regular expressions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down, keeping the relevant parts. By now you have 2 options:

**Option 1** (number followed by "`nodule`"):

```
([0-4]\.\d+\s*[mM]{2})[\s\S]{0,24}[Nn]odule
```

**Option 2** ("`nodule`" followed by number):

```
[Nn]odule[\s\S]{0,24}([0-4]\.\d+\s*[mM]{2})
```

---

You should know the regex engine is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). It means that `[\s\S]{1,24}` will try to match as much as it can, matching the number that is not necessarily closest to "`nodule`". For example,

```
Pattern: [Nn]odule[\s\S]{0,24}([0-4]\.\d+\s*[mM]{2})

Text: ... nodule measured 1.4 mm. Another 3.2 mm ...
                                          ^    ^
                                          |    |
          matches this second occurence.  +----+
```

To fix this, add an extra **`?`** after a quantifier to make it [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy). So, instead of using `[\s\S]{0,24}`, use `[\s\S]{0,24}?`.

---

> For example, the largest nodule which is located in the right lower lobe and currently measures 4.4 mm

This example here has "`nodule`" separated by more than 24 chars. You should increase the number of characters in between. Maybe `[\s\S]{0,70}?`.

---

> So I am trying a negative lookbehind

Lookbehinds only assert text that is immediately before a certain position. To avoid it, I recommend matching the text "`previously measured`", consuming some characters around it. So, how do you know not to consider those cases? Easy, don't create a capture. So you will be matching something like

```
[\s\S]{0,10}previously measured[\s\S]{0,10}
```

and discarding the match because it didn't return any groups. Moreover, you could include different exceptions here:

```
[\s\S]{0,10}(?:previously measured|previous scan|another patient|incorrectly measured)[\s\S]{0,10}
```

---

> if multiple hits are found I would like to only keep the largest size found

You can't do that with regex. Loop in your code to find the largest.

---

#### Result:

With these conditions, we have:

```
[\s\S]{0,10}previously measured[\s\S]{0,10}|([0-4]\.\d+\s*[mM]{2})[\s\S]{0,70}?[Nn]odule|[Nn]odule[\s\S]{0,70}?([0-4]\.\d+\s*[mM]{2})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qP7jJ9/1)

---

#### Extra conditions to check

Maybe, one of the following options turns useful in order to reduce false positives:

1. Don't allow to match after a newline.
2. Don't match if there's a full stop between "`nodule`" and the number.
3. Look for a date near the measure.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1) using lookbehinds:

```
(?<!previously measured )(?<![0-9.])([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?) ?mm
```

The first checks if `"previously measured "` is not before the number, the second checks if there are no digits or a dot before the number (otherwise the 4 after the dot will match. Keep in mind that a regex engine returns the first result on the left).

2) using capture groups:

```
previously measured [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)? ?mm|([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?) ?mm
```

The idea is to match what you want to avoid before. When the capture group 1 exists, you have got a result.

About the biggest number, use the `re.findall` method and take the biggest result after (a regex can't solve this kind of things).

Answer (score 1):

If there need to be `nodule` word nearby, you can try with:

```
(?:((?<!previously measured\s)\d+.\d+\s*mm)(?:[^.?!\n]*?)?nodule|nodule(?:[^.?!\n]*?((?<!previously measured\s)\d+.\d+\s*mm))?)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uB9lH1/3)

It will match if:

- the nodule is in the same sentence as value in mm (the `[^.?!\n]`
  should prevent it, however word like Mr.,decimals, etc. will disturb the
  match), you can replace it with `.+?` ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uB9lH1/4)) however it could match between sentences
- the value is before, or after word nodule (in this oreder, if there
  is value before, it will be matched first),
- values will be captured in groups: before - \1, after - \2,
- it should be used with g and i modes

Other similar solution would be:

```
(?=((?<!previously measured\s)\d+.\d+ mm)[^.?!]+nodule)|(?=nodule[^.?!]+((?<!previously measured\s)\d+\.\d+ mm))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uB9lH1/2)

based only on lookarounds, it will not directly match text but zero-lenght position, and will capture values into groups.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to this problem I ended up tokenizing the reports into individual sentences using the nltk module. The final regex expression which works for all instances is:

```
nodule_search = "[\s\S]{0,10}(?:previously measured|compared to )[\s\S]{0,10}|(\d[\.,]\d+|\d+|\d\d[\.,]\d+)\s*[mM]{2}[\s\S]{0,40}?[Nn]odule|[Nn]odule[\s\S]{0,40}?(\d[\.,]\d+|\d+|\d\d[\.,]\d+)\s*[mM]{2}"
```

So in this instance I ended up not doing a negative lookbehind but did a capture groups instead.

Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: Thank you for contributing with the solution that you actually implemented. It's very constructive to see what a question turns up to.